# Streaming audio spereated from a video over network to android device

Tags: c#, android, synchronization, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I have a video file and I want to play it on one computer (preferably with C#), but stream the audio to an android device and let it play there synchronous to the video content over network.

Do you have any tips how I can achieve that?
Any library or code examples are welcome :)

Comment: so if I understand, you want to play a video from your computer on your android device?